# Multiple desktop app for windows 7/8

Tags: windows

Do you know of a good software that enables you to have multiple desktops on windows 7/8? Some requirements include:

- Very user friendly
- Easy to switch between desktops
- Persistent settings (everything should be the same after you shutdown/reboot)
- The ability to have different wallpapers and different apps running on each desktop

Comment: you mean like what Linux does?

Comment: FWIW I've personally used about half of the suggested software in Synetech's post in the past. I always end up hitting a problem at some point. Multiple monitors with http://winsplit-revolution.com/ is the only long term solution I've found.

Comment: @Richard, WinSplit does not seem to be a virtual-desktop app; it is a window-management app (and Flavius wasn't asking about multiple-monitor, rather multiple desktops).

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of *[virtual-desktop programs](http://slashdot.org/story/06/10/13/0517224/virtual-desktops-on-windows)*.

- [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/) has been gaining in popularity and functionality over the years.
- [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) frequently appears near the top of search results (for a reason).
- [Virtual Dimension](http://virt-dimension.sourceforge.net/#screenshots) has some nice functions including transparencies.
- [Finestra](http://vdm.codeplex.com/) is nice and easy to use.
- [Sysinternals Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881) is a simple virtual desktop manager.
- [Virtual Desktop Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-xp) is a PowerToy shell-extension from Microsoft.

---

Personally, I like the Microsoft *Virtual Desktop Manager* best because it:

- Puts a little toolband in the taskbar, making it incredibly easy to use
- Hotkey support includes the <kbd>Win</kbd> key (unlike a lot of programs)
- Is very low profile (you can configure it to show either four buttons or just one)
- Can be configured to not show animations (which while nifty feels snappier without)
- Supports separate wallpapers for each desktop
- Has an overview mode to see everything at a glance
- Doesn’t require running a new shell for each desktop
- It’s a shell-extension, so it integrates as part of Explorer, not a separately running program
- Its performance is top-notch and switches are instantaneous

Comment: have you used Dexpot ? is it good on the long run ? Im having some trouble with it

Comment: I used it a while back when it was still new. It was easy to use but had some great, advanced features that other virtual desktop programs of the time did not. What problems are you having with it?

Comment: one problem was that it crashes when I try to set different wallpaper to each desktop, it doesn't happen if I dont set an image but just color, its uses less memory this way aniway... 

another problem was that it didn't remembered how I set the icons, but I think it was because my laptop crashed twice, so maybe the software didn't had the chance to save the settings

another problem was when I got to work and pluged in an external display to my laptop, everything got messed up again... so.. any suggestions, solutions are welcome

Comment: I can’t confirm if it works in Windows 7 just this moment (I’m in XP right now), but I’m fairly sure I have used it in 7 without issue.

Comment: According to this article - http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/a-new-virtual-desktop-tool-from-microsofts-windows-sysinternals-team/791 - SysInternals Desktops is "more efficient .. resource management" and newer. The current release was published Oct 17th, 2012.

Comment: *> SysInternals Desktops is "more efficient .. resource management" and newer.*   It has been updated to 2.0 just this past month. Clearly it’s still being maintained which is  good thing. (You can submit bug-reports and feature-requests at the [forums](http://forum.sysinternals.com/), and maybe they will be fixed/implemented.)

Answer (score 1):

1 year ago I enjoyed the program "Virtuawin"  (opensource)
http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/

Portable version by portableapps:
http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/virtuawin_portable

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recently made a multiple desktop app for Windows 7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881

Although it doesn't say specifically, it looks like the spiritual successor to the Virtual Desktop Monitor that Synetech posted in his answer.